# Space between website edge and footer

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

I can not seem to be able to remove this small space between my footer and website. The space only shows up if the screen has been resized to less than width:500px;. The

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRlJX.jpg

```
<footer class="footer">
            <div class="left-side">
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Back to top</a>
                </div>
                <p>Loo Inc &copy; 2016</p>
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <div>
                    <h3>Social Media</h3>
                    <img src="images/icons/facebook.png" alt="facebook social media icon"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheLooApp/" target="_blank" alt="link to our facebook profile.">facebook.com </a> <br/>
                    <img src="images/icons/twitter.png" alt="twitter social media icon"> <a href="https://www.twitter.com/TheLooApp" target="_blank" alt="Link to our twitter profile.">twitter.com</a> <br/>
                    <img src="images/icons/instagram.png" alt="instagram social media icon"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/TheLooApp" target="_blank" alt="Link to our instagram profile.">instagram.com </a> <br/>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <p>E-mail us at: <a href="mailto:support@company.com">loo@mail.com</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side">
                <p class="our_services">
                    <h3> Payment methods </h3>
                    <img src="images/icons/mc.png" alt="Icon with MasterCard logo. ">
                    <img src="images/icons/visa.png" alt="Icon with Visa logo.">
                    <img src="images/icons/paypal.png" alt="Icon with PayPal logo.">
                    <img src="images/icons/vipps.png" alt="Icon with Vipps logo.">
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4hxe30er/

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to debug your code with only a fraction of your html structure but, from the JSFiddle, you should be able to fix that gap by removing the `margin-bottom: 40px;` line inside `@media (max-width: 50em) { }`.